# String Hexadecimal cortada ao fazer insert com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Boa tarde pessoal!
Gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês para solucionar um problema que está acontecendo comigo.
Tenho uma string em hexadecimal contendo uma imagens que deve ser adicionada ao banco de dados, quando faço o insert com o PDO sem o bindValue, passando o valor da variável diretamente pra string SQL, funciona perfeitamente:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO arquivos (arquivo) Value($this->Arquivo)";

try{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
//outros campos...
$stmt->execute();
}...
```

no entanto, se eu fizer via bindValue:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO arquivos (arquivo) Value(:Arquivo)";
try{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( ':Arquivo', $this->Arquivo );
$stmt->execute();
}...
```

o valor é cortado, e a imagem fica corrompida.

Como corrijo isso? é alguma configuração? Gostaria de utilizar tudo via bindValue.

Comment: Seu campo é um blob?

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo utilizado para salvar o arquivo em hexadecimal?

Comment: @AllanAndrade É um campo Blob

Comment: Veja se assim funciona: `$stmt->bindValue( ':Arquivo', $this->Arquivo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray) está certo.

Para grandes conteúdos (tipo BLOB por exemplo), deve informar o data type: `PDO::PARAM_LOB`

O código ficaria assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO arquivos (arquivo) Value(:Arquivo)";
try{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindValue( ':Arquivo', $this->Arquivo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Outra versão:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO arquivos (arquivo) Value(?)";
try{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->Arquivo, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Caso não funcione, adicione o código abaixo antes do `EXECUTE`, e cheque se esta propriedade contém realmente a string correta:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($this->Arquivo);
echo '</pre>';
```

Sugiro que leia este artigo sobre o assunto: [Gravando arquivos em BD usando PDO do PHP](http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2011/03/gravando-arquivos-em-bd.html)

Comment: Fiz conforme mencionado acima, e o mesmo erro persiste, uma diferença sobre o artigo informado, é que a string já vem pronta para fazer uma gravação, a partir de uma outra aplicação, somente pego a string hexadecimal com aproximadamente 500kb e faço a gravação da mesma. Com o parâmetro PDO::PARAM_LOB, também não funcionou, a string também é cortada.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, testa novamente e me diz se deu certo.

Comment: A string aparece do modo correto: 0xffd8ffe000104a46494600010100000100..., porém quando grava o início da sring é 0x3078666664386666653030303130346134363439